# Como puedo enviar un email con un archivo adjunto mediante onesignal?

Tags: java

**JAVA**

Estoy haciendo un post mediante este link "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications" para enviar emails, pero no se como enviar archivos adjuntos

```
String url = "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications";

Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

map.put("app_id", "{miIdApp}");
map.put("include_email_tokens", emails);
map.put("email_subject", "Estado de transacción");
map.put("email_body", "{Aqui va el body del email implementado en HTML}");

HttpEntity<Map<String, Object>> entity = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);

ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, entity, String.class);
```